# Rendering problem

Tags: rendering, materials, light, eevee-render-engine, color

I have a problem with the rendering of my scene, instead of having a nice gradation as on the real time rendering, I have this result, with plain colors, it's very weird, I don't know the reason for this, can you please help me ? Thank you so much (the render engine is Eevee[image])

[image]

Comment: Check if your *Subdivision Surface* modifier has the same number of subdivision for the render.

Comment: That was it! Thanks :))